# List of all database without a specific index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, index

I am working on a Multi Tenant System. In which we have one Manager DB and Each client has a Company DB.

[image]

Now all of these database have the same Table Schema.

But some of them have a missing Index on a certain Table.

Is there a way to get a list of Databases with that missing index using SQL? We are using SQL-Server 2012

**EDIT:**

Let's say `Company_1` has an index on `TableA`called `IX_Missing_Index` - but `Company_2` and `Company_3` DO NOT have the index 'IX_Missing_Index' - So all I need in the result set is Company_2 and Company_3

e.g. like this

```
    Database Without index IX_Missing_Index
    ----------------------------------------------
    Company_2
    Company_3
```

Comment: Do you want to get list of the indexes which is available in DB Company_1 but not in Company_2 or you want list of missing index that SQL Server optimizer suggest to create on objects?

Comment: @RajeshRanjan see my Edit

Comment: Are you looking for databases without such an index `on TableA` or in general? (In other words, some databases may have an index called `IX_Missing_Index` but on a different table. Should they show up in your query or not?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #dbs(db sysname);

DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max) = N'INSERT #dbs SELECT ''?''
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ?.sys.tables WHERE name = N''TableA'')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ?.sys.indexes AS i
    INNER JOIN ?.sys.tables AS t
    ON i.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
    WHERE t.name = N''TableA''
      AND i.name = N''IX_Missing_Index'');';

EXEC master.dbo.sp_foreachdb @command = @cmd, @user_only = 1;

SELECT db FROM #dbs;

DROP TABLE #dbs;
```

You can get `sp_foreachdb` [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) (it is also being open sourced and added to Brent Ozar Unlimited's [SQL Server First Responder Kit](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/448)).

Answer (score 0):

It's a quick one-off kludge, but if you just want to get on with your day:

```
--Create a global temp table
create table ##MissingIndex (DbName sysname)

--Run the following query to generate dynamic sql statements
--NOTE: Change **MissingIndexName** to your index name
select ' insert into ##MissingIndex select ''' + name + ''' where not exists (select * from ' + name + '.sys.indexes where name=''**MissingIndexName**'')' from sys.databases where database_id>4

--run the generated statements

--Then
select * from ##missingindex order by DbName
```

I'm sure there are slicker ways using ForEachDB, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `IDX_MY_INDEX` by your index name.

in my example below I run it with '`IDX_SegmentID_Tier1`'which is one index that I have in only 3 of my databases and you can see the picture how it looks like.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY NORMAL;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    DECLARE  @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ,@vCrlf CHAR(2);

    SELECT  @vCrlf = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10);

select @sql = 'select DATABASE_NAME=db_name(), THE_INDEX_EXIST= CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * from sys.indexes where name like ''IDX_MY_INDEX'')  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END '


SET @SQL = (
            SELECT STUFF(
  (SELECT N'  ' + ' USE ' + QUOTENAME(name) +';' + @vCrlf + @SQL + @vCrlf    
                                FROM SYS.DATABASES SD
                                WHERE SD.STATE_DESC = 'ONLINE' -->Skips the database if it is not online
                                  AND SD.COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL > 80  

      FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'')
)

EXECUTE MASTER.DBO.sp_executesql @SQL
```

[image]